# useEffect doesn't want to update my display

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, render, use-effect

I'm new here so take it easy :-)

I have a feeling I'm using useEffect incorrectly. Basically I have a few radio buttons on the page. When they are change/clicked I call a function that sets a variable call state to the selected item. The variable is also the trigger for the useEffect, so that fires and I perform some filter on an object variable called FilteredProjects.

In the console, when I log this out it has the correct values in them but the screen isn't updating with them, Is this because I'm not storing that value in state?

Here is the code section:(I've trimmed the code to the first use of the variable FilteredProject)

```
const [state,setstate] = useState(0)

let projectsList = useSelector(state=>state.projectReducer.projects)
let filteredProject = projectsList

  useEffect(() => {
    if(projectsList) {
      if(state == "All") {
        //show all statuses
        setfilteredProject(projectsList)
      } else{
        //single filter
        filteredProject = projectsList.filter(o => o.state === state);
      }
    }
}, [state])

function toggleStatus(e){
  console.log("state changed");
  setstate(e.value)
}


    return (
      <div className="px-2 py-4 ">
        <div className="card h-fit my-4 lg:w-12/12">
        <div className='form-check form-check-inline'><input className='form-check-input appearance-none h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white checked:bg-blue-600 checked:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none transition duration-200 mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2 cursor-pointer' name='status' type='radio' id='status' onClick={(e)=>toggleStatus(e.target)} value='All' defaultChecked={true}></input><label className='form-check-label inline-block text-gray-800 font-normal mr-2' ><b>All Statuses</b> </label></div>
        <div className='form-check form-check-inline'><input className='form-check-input appearance-none h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white checked:bg-blue-600 checked:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none transition duration-200 mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2 cursor-pointer' name='status' type='radio' id='status' onClick={(e)=>toggleStatus(e.target)} value='Fundraising' defaultChecked={false}></input><label className='form-check-label inline-block text-gray-800 font-normal mr-2' >Fundrasing </label></div>
        <div className='form-check form-check-inline'><input className='form-check-input appearance-none h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white checked:bg-blue-600 checked:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none transition duration-200 mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2 cursor-pointer' name='status' type='radio' id='status' onClick={(e)=>toggleStatus(e.target)} value='Successful' defaultChecked={false}></input><label className='form-check-label inline-block text-gray-800 font-normal mr-2' >Successful </label></div>
        <div className='form-check form-check-inline'><input className='form-check-input appearance-none h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white checked:bg-blue-600 checked:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none transition duration-200 mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2 cursor-pointer' name='status' type='radio' id='status' onClick={(e)=>toggleStatus(e.target)} value='Expired' defaultChecked={false}></input><label className='form-check-label inline-block text-gray-800 font-normal mr-2' >Expired </label></div>
        </div>
        <div className=" my-2 lg:my-0 lg:mx-2 grid sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-2 grid-cols-1">
          {filteredProject.....
```

Comment: Is `filteredProject` being tracked in state? You're just setting the variable (`filteredProject = ...`) which won't trigger any updates.

Comment: post all your component, we are missing a lot of usefull information (where setfilteredProject come from ?). For this specific problem I would have used useMemo instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This is worked for me like this, You need to update the state.

const [radioValue, setRadioValue] = useState("male");
const [data, setData] = useState("");

const handleChange = (e) => {
 console.log(e.target.value);
 setRadioValue(e.target.value);
};

useEffect(() => {
if (radioValue === "male") {
  setData("This is Male");
} else {
  setData("This is FeMale");
}
}, [radioValue]);

return (
<div className="App">
  Male
  <input
    name="gender"
    type="radio"
    value="male"
    defaultChecked
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
  Female
  <input
    name="gender"
    type="radio"
    value="female"
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
  <div>
    <h3>{data}</h3>
  </div>
</div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks all, great solutions, I went with the one Priyen, as it fit my model better for filtering, and I've applied it to about 3 different filters now on the same page and it works very very smoothly. thanks all

Answer (score 0):

you should try to save filteredProject as state that way when the value change the screen will rerender and should change the display.

Answer (score 0):

You can use useEffect like this and you can update state :

```
const ButtonUpdate = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const [name, setName] = useState('om')

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Hi ${name} you clicked ${count} times`)
  });
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hi {name} you clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setName(name === 'om' ? 'krishn' : 'Boldo`)}>
        Change name
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```